# How to select a span who has a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I need to put the word "hello" in the span that contains the attribute "data-whatever", ie for this span:

```
<span data-whatever="nomatterwhat"> </ span>
```

I need to do this:

```
$ ("span[data-whatever]").html("hello");
```

Note that this above is with JQuery, but I need to know how to do the same with pure javascript.

Comment: Use DOM API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Try googling for "css attribute selector".

Comment: I'm not agree with @torazaburo, that question you're linking is not a duplicate of this one. That's css, if you know what's the relation between that answers and what I need here, then good for you, but I have no Idea on how to resolve my question with that post you're linking.

Comment: Hi Roberto. So first of all you did not read the manual about CSS selectors, or about finding elements using CSS selectors using JavaScript. By "manual", I mean any of a hundred documentation pages, tutorials, introductions, or Google results pages. Now you have failed to read the answers to the question this one was marked as a duplicate of, in particular the second answer, which clearly states "Note this can also be used in a JQuery selector, or using `document.querySelector`". You'd find your progress as a programmer would go much faster if you slowed down and read and digested things.

Comment: Ok, I understand, it's just that the probability to find that answer on a question that has no relation to mine, could be difficult... Or very difficult when the "Questions that may already have your answer", which was displayed when I was making the ask, doesn't show the post you're linking.

Comment: *A question that has no relation to mine* On the contrary, it has a very strong relationship to yours to the point of being virtually identical. Both questions are precisely about how to select elements with attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

`document.querySelector('span[data-whatever]').innerHTML = "You text";`

Comment: This won't work at all.

Comment: it works on my case, ty so much

Comment: @torazaburo OP has accepted it. Can you tell what's wrong with this answer, so that I can improve it. Should i loop through whatever `querySelectorAll` returns and set the innerHTML or use `querySelector`?

Comment: What's wrong with it is that it doesn't work. `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, which has no `innerHTML` property. It means absolutely nothing that the OP accepted, other than that he didn't actually try it. Whether you loop or use `querySelector` depends on the OP's intent--whether he wants to do this for all such elements, or expects to have just one.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('span');
el.forEach(function(item){
  if(item.hasAttribute('data-whatever')){
    item.innerHTML = 'Hello';
  }
})
```

Comment: I updated the code to fix it.

Comment: This is unlikely to work in all browsers, since the result of `querySelectorAll` is a `NodeList` which may not have a `forEach` method. In any case, why not just use an attribute selector to start with?